# How to add a new tab to JTabbedPane with a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want to create new tabs in `tabbedpane` when new option is clicked. But new tab should include the panel with a text area on same position as in the first tab which I created through drag and drop in netbeans. I create one tab and want new instance of that tab as other tabs how can I do that?

I am creating a notepad application and I want to add the functionality of new files in the form of tabs in `tabbedpane`. I have created one tab through drag and drop in netbeans. but I don't know how to use this instance in new tab when new option is clicked.

```
//This is the code to create new panel but it is not working 
int i= 1;
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                           
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp = jPanel1; // jPanel1 is the panel created by drag and drop.
    // i cantains text area.
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("untitled"+i,jp);   
    i++;
}
```

I want the application to create new tabs as tabs created in netbeans or dev etc.

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] and explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating JTabbedPane when new tab is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332040/updating-jtabbedpane-when-new-tab-is-added)

Answer (score 0):

```
jp = jPanel1; // jPanel1 is the panel created by drag and drop.
```

You can't share components. Swing components can only have a single parent.

So you need to create a new instance of JPanel and a new Instance of JTextArea.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLaout() );
panel.add( textArea );
jTabbedPane1.addTab("untitled"+i, panel);
```

Now the text area will fill the space available in the tabbed pane.

You don't event need the JPanel if all you want is a text area on the tab. Just add the new text area to the tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
   JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea();  
   ta1.setBounds(10, 10,100 , 100);
   jp1.add(ta1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jp1);
   jp1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(   jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(ta1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 501, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(         jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(ta1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 321, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("untitled",jp1);
```

//this is the right answer to my question this is the way to pass a text area with a panel in the tabbed pane